# Finding singularities at z=0

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\exp\left(\frac{\cos(z)-1}{z^2}\right)^2$$
1. has a removable singularity at $z=0$
2. pole of order $2$ in $z=0$
3. pole of order $4$ in $z=0$
4. has a essential singularity at $z=0$
please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Although the formula is still ambiguous, I have added as much latex as I could without changing the statement (which was ambiguous). Unfortunately, this looks like a homework question. It would be good to show some effort, thoughts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the function in parenthesis has a pole. You want to show that if $f$ has a pole, then $\exp(f)$ has an essential singularity.

Edit: Actually, as it's written now the function does not have a pole, it is analytic, so $\exp(f)$ is also analytic, and has a removable singularity.